# Reputation per Day one day off

Tags: bug, reputation

Why is my Reputation per Day Graph always displaying results a day off?

[image: No reputation changes on that day]

When I click the day after the one I want I will get the correct results below. But this means, I cannot watch the reputation changes of today as there is no "tomorrow" clickable in the graph yet. And it's very fiddly to press on this very tiny space just above the horizontal axis on a day after the one I want my results to be shown when there was no reputation change on that day. It works with one or two pixels high to click on this. But this seems to be a Bug on SE?

Comment: what os, browser and version are you using? None of that works for me, (I don't even get the box with the daily stats.)

Comment: This seems to of been addressed on the main meta: [Reputation for graph is off by a day](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/259692/278094)

Comment: Yeah, that's the thing. It's already listed as a bug there and even for quite some time. I'm on the latest Chrome, Windows 7.